# Subtracting mean from calculation puts answer in list?

Tags: list, wolfram-mathematica

I have a function that cycles through two sperate lists and combines them into one as follows:

```
spread = Table[{gld[[i, 1]], (gld[[i, 2]] - gdx[[i, 2]]) }, 
               {i, 1, Length[gld], 1}]
```

This works fine, and generates answers in the form:

```
{{2009, 6, 1}, 52.72}
```

But when I add a subtraction, as follows:

```
spread = Table[{gld[[i, 1]], (gld[[i, 2]] - gdx[[i, 2]]) - meanspread }, 
               {i, 1, Length[gld], 1}]
```

I get answers in the format:

```
{{2009, 6, 1}, {-20.2896}}
```

This causes issues when I want to use DateLinePlot (all the data is in the extreme right of the graph, and the graph is not usable.

Can anyone suggest what might be happening here and how I may avoid it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely `meanspread` is not a number, but a single-item list, such as `{1.1}`.  It's impossible to tell without knowing more details and having a sample of all data/variables you're using.

Answer (score 3):

I don't get this, recreating your inputs as best I can.  It really depends on how you're computing `meanspread`.

```
(*In[2]:= *)
gld = FinancialData["NYSE:GLD", "Close", {"June 1, 2009", DateString[], "Day"}];
gdx = FinancialData["NYSE:GDX", "Close", {"June 1, 2009", DateString[], "Day"}];

(*In[5]:= *)
First[spread = Table[{gld[[i, 1]], (gld[[i, 2]] - gdx[[i, 2]])}, {i, 1, Length[gld], 1}]]

(*Out[5]= *)
{{2009, 6, 1}, 52.72}

(*In[8]:= *)
meanspread = Mean[spread[[All, 2]]]

(*Out[8]= *)
74.0373

(*In[9]:= *)
First[Table[{gld[[i, 1]], (gld[[i, 2]] - gdx[[i, 2]]) - meanspread}, {i, 1, Length[gld], 1}]]

(*Out[9]= *)
{{2009, 6, 1}, -21.3173}
```

Comment: Good guess about what's behind the OP's data. Surely you must be an seasoned investor.

Comment: @Sjoerd I just asked Wolfram|Alpha what 'gld' and 'gdx' were, and the numbers worked out.  Good use of descriptive variable names by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would benefit from a simpler construction.

```
spread = {gld[[All, 1]], gld[[All, 2]] - gdx[[All, 2]] - meanspread}\[Transpose]
```

As already said, if `meanspread` is a single numerical value, and not a list, the output should be correct.